# Django and ajax cross domain request from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been reading a lot of post about this but couldn't find a solution that works. I have a website with https connection and It makes an ajax request to panoramio api that only looks like to run over http. My ajax code is on jquery:

```
    var url = "http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=full&from=0&to=20&minx={}&miny={}&maxx={}&maxy={}&size=medium&mapfilter=true"
    var url_query = url.format(longitud -0.2, latitud -0.2, longitud +0.2, latitud +0.2)

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url_query,
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            $('#select_pics').empty();
            for (var photo = 0; photo <data["photos"].length; photo++){
                $('#select_pics').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",JSON.stringify(data["photos"][photo]) ).attr("data-img-src", data["photos"][photo]["photo_file_url"]));
            }

            $("#paronamio").show()
            $("select").imagepicker()

            $("#show_images").show()
        }
```

In the side of Django I have set the following variables in settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'panoramio.com',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

the error in the chrome console is the following:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.com/create/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=full&from=0&to=20&minx=-…er=true&callback=jQuery214048928201338276267_1449402360941&_=1449402360942'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

If you need aditional information just request it, thanks :)

Comment: It seems it has nothing to do with your server, you can remove `python` and `django` tag from your question. Also you don't have to allow CORS to panpramio.com from your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.This is not a django problem, is the way browsers work: they don't allow [active mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent) for security reasons.
If the user access a site over HTTPS than all the links of this application have to be secure (HTTPS) otherwise the browser will block them.

2.It seems panoramio API supports https connection to

```
https://ssl.panoramio.com
```

At least trying your query

```
https://ssl.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=full&from=0&to=20&minx={}&miny={}&maxx={}&maxy={}&size=medium&mapfilter=true"
```

worked responding with a JSON file.